# "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:" while trying to save an edited workbook with save()

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlwt, errno

I have an .xls file in the same directory with my .py file.
Although it works fine if I'm not overwriting an existing file.

```
import xlrd, xlwt
from xlutils.copy import copy

rb2=xlrd.open_workbook("TEST_info.xls",on_demand=True)

wb2=copy(rb2)
ws2=wb2.get_sheet(0)
ws2.write(0,1,'DIFFERENt value')
wb2.save("TEST_info.xls")
```

> File
> "C:\Python_User\Excel_spreadsheet_proj\excel_proj_env\Scripts\main.py",
> line 9, in 
> wb2.save("TEST_info.xls")   File "C:\Python_User\Excel_spreadsheet_proj\excel_proj_env\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py",
> line 710, in save
> doc.save(filename_or_stream, self.get_biff_data())   File "C:\Python_User\Excel_spreadsheet_proj\excel_proj_env\lib\site-packages\xlwt\CompoundDoc.py",
> line 262, in save
> f = open(file_name_or_filelike_obj, 'w+b')
> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'TEST_info.xls'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with importing "os" and writing:

```
if(os.path.exists(file)):
    os.remove(file)
wb.save(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs at https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/on_demand.html:

> `on_demand=True` and `BIFF version >= 5.0`: `open_workbook()` loads global data and returns without releasing resources.

You should either set `on_demand=True` to `False` so `rb2` releases the underlying resources, or call `rb2.release_resources()` befor trying to save the copy.